# How to install libpq.so.4.x on Debian 9

Tags: compiling, postgresql, ld

I try to compil from source PHP5.3.29 on Debian 9. The make command  stopped in error at this step

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath=/opt/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.1u/lib,-rpath=/opt/CURL/curl-7.26.0/lib" make
.../...
(.text+0x5d7e): warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.1, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.1, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.1, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.1, needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-client.a(osdep.o): undefined reference to symbol 'TLS_server_method@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:277: recipe for target 'sapi/fpm/php-fpm' failed
make: *** [sapi/fpm/php-fpm] Error 1
```

Like I compiled old version of OpenSSL and Curl. I suppect libpq.so is not old enough

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Aug  9 23:22 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so -> libpq.so.5.9
```

I don't know how to find the source of libpq.so.4.x which is a PostgreSQL library.

Comment: Did you delete your previous questions on the topic? If so, this might have been answered already, but wouldn’t it be simpler for you to stay on Debian 8, which includes PHP 5.6.39, or even Debian 7 (for which extended support is available), which has PHP 5.4.45? Or are PHP 5.6, 5.4 and 5.3 mutually incompatible?

Comment: @Stephen Kitt. Yes I deleted it because I found this [solution] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379215/installing-php-5-3-on-debian-stretch-9) I'm already in DEBIAN I can not downgrade the OS. I already installed PHP 5.6.39 from source.

Comment: The solution above doesn't manage PHP-FPM. The error is arriving during php-fpm compilation step

Comment: Mixing libssl versions eg using the wrong version, even if it compiles, it's a recipe for disaster. You would be better off using containers technology or some other isolation technology with the actual Debian binaries of the versions you need.

Comment: @Rui it’s doable, as long as you never link two libraries which each need different versions of `libssl` (with different sonames).

Comment: @StephenKitt Never said it is not doable, I even used to "own" a server running a dual stack PHP5+PHP7 in Debian 9 (in a server not exposed to the Internet)...some sites used PHP5, others PHP7...it just that does not seem doable by the type of questions the OP is asking, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The catalog of [Debian snapshots of `libpq4`](https://snapshot.debian.org/binary/libpq4/) indicates that the last version of PostgreSQL to provide `libpq4` was the 8.1 series; you can get the source code for the last release of that (8.1.23) [from PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v8.1.23/).

(You could try using the binary packages from snapshots, but I’m not sure the dependencies would be satisfiable without conflict in Debian 9.)